# "AttributeError: __pydantic_private__"--Chroma langchain vectorstore runs into AttributeError when run

Tags: python, chatbot, pydantic, py-langchain, chromadb

I followed [langchain's documentation of a chatbot](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/), and my chatbot project was working fine 1~2 months ago. However, after reinstalling dependencies, etc, I've run into the error "AttributeError: **pydantic_private**". Tracking this error down, it's located in BaseModel class of the pydantic package, where it calls "self.**pydantic_private**".  I'm not sure why this error is thrown, as "**pydantic_private**" very much exists as an attribute in the BaseModel class.

I have suspicions that I reinstalled the wrong version of packages, which may have led to this problem. Has anyone ran into this problem / any thoughts on solving it?

Here is the entire block of code (located in the BaseModel class of the pydantic package), where the error is thrown when it calls "self.**pydantic_private**":

````
def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        if name in self.__class_vars__:
            raise AttributeError(
                f'{name!r} is a ClassVar of `{self.__class__.__name__}` and cannot be set on an instance. '
                f'If you want to set a value on the class, use `{self.__class__.__name__}.{name} = value`.'
            )
        elif not _fields.is_valid_field_name(name):
            if self.__pydantic_private__ is None or name not in self.__private_attributes__:
                _object_setattr(self, name, value)
            else:
                attribute = self.__private_attributes__[name]
                if hasattr(attribute, '__set__'):
                    attribute.__set__(self, value)  # type: ignore
                else:
                    self.__pydantic_private__[name] = value
            return
        elif self.model_config.get('frozen', None):
            error: pydantic_core.InitErrorDetails = {
                'type': 'frozen_instance',
                'loc': (name,),
                'input': value,
            }
            raise pydantic_core.ValidationError.from_exception_data(self.__class__.__name__, [error])
        elif getattr(self.model_fields.get(name), 'frozen', False):
            error: pydantic_core.InitErrorDetails = {
                'type': 'frozen_field',
                'loc': (name,),
                'input': value,
            }
            raise pydantic_core.ValidationError.from_exception_data(self.__class__.__name__, [error])

        attr = getattr(self.__class__, name, None)
        if isinstance(attr, property):
            attr.__set__(self, value)
        elif self.model_config.get('validate_assignment', None):
            self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_assignment(self, name, value)
        elif self.model_config.get('extra') != 'allow' and name not in self.model_fields:
            # TODO - matching error
            raise ValueError(f'"{self.__class__.__name__}" object has no field "{name}"')
        elif self.model_config.get('extra') == 'allow' and name not in self.model_fields:
            # SAFETY: __pydantic_extra__ is not None when extra = 'allow'
            self.__pydantic_extra__[name] = value  # type: ignore
        else:
            self.__dict__[name] = value
            self.__pydantic_fields_set__.add(name)```
````

I've tried a different version of chromadb, but to no avail. Not quite sure what the problem is, as this program was working 1~2 months ago.

Comment: Maybe you can try `pydantic v1`?

Comment: Not sure if it was supposed to be pydantic v1, but turns out it was a package version problem.  I reinstalled packages one by one (didn't use requirements.txt), and that eventually got me the right version (now the program is working).